# How do you pass props to a react motion styled component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, framer-motion

**The Problem**

I have some code that use to work. I wanted to use this code in a new project but because of the updates to either create-react-app (npx), styled-components or framer-motion; this method no longer works.

**What previously worked**

Here is the code that use to work:

```
const StyledMotionComponent = motion(
    styled.div((props) => ({
        transform: props.scale,
        position: "absolute",
        top: "0",
        right: "0",
        bottom: "0",
        left: "0",
        display: "flex",

        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        zIndex: "-1",
    }))
);
```

I could then pass in a value like this:

```
<StyledMotionComponent scale="0.2" />
```

**The question**

So how do I recreate this with the current version of `npx create-react-app ./`(react ^17.0.2), the current version of framer-motion(^5.5.5) and the current version of styled-components(^5.3.3).

**My failed attempts to solve the problem**

```
const StyledMotionComponent = (props) => {
    styled(motion.div)`
        transform: props.scale;
        position: "absolute";
        top: "0";
        right: "0";
        bottom: "0";
        left: "0";
        display: "flex";
        justify-content: "center";
        align-items: "center";
        z-index: "-1";
    `;
};


const StyledMotionComponent = motion((props) => {
    return styled.div`
        transform: props.scale;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;

        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: -1;
    `;
});

const StyledMotionComponent = styled(motion.div).attrs((props) => ({
    initial: { scale: props.scale },
}))`
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: -1;
`;
```

This final one works but the animation is extremely jittery. It seems to be using too much memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close with those last couple of attempts. This is what you are looking for:

```
const StyledMotionComponent = styled(motion.div)`
    transform: scale(${({scale}) => scale});
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: -1;
`;
```

Any attempt that was doing something like `() => styled` would be laggy because it would be creating the styled instance over and over again.

Here is a (new) example of this working
https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-styled-component-and-motion-combination-llmm3

Comment: This answer does not contain the props. You are creating a styled component that has access to the framer-motion API but it's the props that I also need to access. i.e. "transform: props.scale"

Comment: Ahh. Sorry I missed that. I edited my answer

Comment: Your edit doesn't cause an error but the css is now very strange. Everything appears to the bottom right of where it was before.

Comment: I just tried removing all the speech marks from the css values, that then corrects the positioning but the component won't scale based on the props and it is jittery. Puzzling.

Comment: Woops @srWebDev. I again edited my answer to include the "scale(***)" keyword in the transform property. It wasn't working before because it wasn't a valid transform property

Comment: That works but it's very jittery, it's using a lot of memory. It's basically the same result as my posted final "My failed attempts to solve the problem".

Comment: I will need more context to help then given that the codesandbox isn't jittery.

Comment: I found the reason for the jittery animation. It had nothing to do with this issue, so you are completely correct. Thank you

Comment: Sick that's great new!